# .NET - Click-Once / Smart Client Applications - Browser Cookie Equivalent?

Tags: .net, cookies, clickonce, smartclient, user-preferences

Is there an equivalent to browser cookies for Smart Client / Click Once application development on .NET 3.5? Some place I can store cookies on the user's machine rather than the server.

Or to put it another way - what file location can you write to from a sandboxed Click-Once app that won't violate good security practices. I don't want to take the app out of the sandbox and run with elevated privileges if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0.aspx). Here's a specific blog post for [ClickOnce apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/01/18/514407.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Isolated storage.  It's like the file system APIs, but more secure and maybe a bit more cumbersome to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Better than cookies, you can use the [Isolated Storage API](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/01/18/514407.aspx) to store files on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking here.
Are you trying to store data? You can do that in Isolated Storage,
although I find myself saving in the System.Environment.SpecialFolder.AppData a lot.

Isolated Storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx